# Why does the Münster compiler believe a pattern match across ++ is non-deterministic?

Tags: compilation, functional-programming, logic-programming, declarative-programming, curry

I recently installed the Münster Curry Compiler to replace the much slower PAKCS that I was using.  The first thing I wanted to test was whether I could use some of the pattern matching features from PAKCS, because I know some implementations (Sloth is the one that comes to mind) don't support all of the pattern matches that PAKCS allows.  So I wrote the following program:

```
import IO

f (a ++ [b]) = a

main = print $ f $ "Hello, World!"
```

This works in PAKCS and prints `Hello, World` as expected, but when compiled with MCC I get the error:

```
Error: cannot duplicate the world
```

My understanding is that this means MCC can't pattern match across `++`, but I don't understand why MCC chooses this error.  `cannot duplicate the world` typically means that the IO is dependent on non-deterministic behavior. This leads me to suspect that MCC believes that my function `f` is non-deterministic.  However to the best of my knowledge `f` is completely deterministic.

What is MCC doing that causes it to think that my function is non-deterministic?

I don't need to know how to fix the program, that is really easy, the following works:

```
import IO

f (a : b @ (_:_)) = a : f b
f [a] = []

main = print $ f $ "Hello, World!"
```

I'm interested in understanding what the compiler is doing here that causes it to error and how that is different from what PAKCS does when it compiles the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything for sure with respect to MCC, but PAKCS translates functional patterns into a (highly) non-deterministic expression. The observed behaviour boils down to the different behaviour of MCC and PAKCS when using non-deterministic computations in IO. In PAKCS a non-deterministic computation is evaluated and the run-time error only occurs if the expression evaluates to more than one result.

That is, you can do the following in PAKCS without getting a run-time-error.

```
REPL> putStrLn ("Hello" ? failed)
"Hello"
```

However, the following computation will yield a (rather late) run-time error.

```
REPL> putStrLn ("Hello" ? "Hello")
Hello
Hello
ERROR: non-determinism in I/O actions occurred!
```

I would guess that the MCC makes a different (and more reasonable ; )) check with respect to non-deterministic computations.

Some advertisement at the end: I usually work with [KiCS2](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/) -- is there a specific reason you're using the MCC?

Edit: If you like to more about functional patterns and their implementation, you should probably take a look at the following paper.

[Declarative Programming with Function Patterns](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~mh/papers/LOPSTR05.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the response! This helps clarify things a bit.  As for working with MCC, I've wanted to use KiCS2, I just had some issues compiling it so I thought I would try MCC instead.

Comment: If you're more interested in why definitions using function patterns are non-deterministic, I've added a paper that explains the implementation for PAKCS.

Comment: And concerning the problems you had with KiCS2: feel free to contact me about that ; )